# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "FormData" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: wffm, express-migration-tool

I am using the migration tool to upgrade from 7.2 to 8.2 including migrating Web Forms for Marketers. The migration completes with warnings. The report states that Web Forms for Marketers failed. The logs show the error below. I have looked through the solution, content tree and database tables, but cannot find anything named 'FormData'.

Has anyone come across this error and know a fix?

`` System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "FormData" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core.Database.DbQueryRunner.Execute(String sql, Object param) in C:\BA\29627f8a956df51d\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core\Database\DbQueryRunner.cs:line 71
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core.Helpers.Retryer.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Execute>b__0() in C:\BA\29627f8a956df51d\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core\Helpers\Retryer.cs:line 45
   at Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core.Helpers.Retryer.Execute[T](Func`1 func) in C:\BA\29627f8a956df51d\src\Sitecore.ExpressMigration.Core\Helpers\Retryer.cs:line 61
ClientConnectionId:b75a88ad-d3d5-4897-ae2b-75d5fbdbf734
Error Number:4701,State:1,Class:16 ``

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it was actually quite a simple case of checking the permissions of the designated user in the connection string. It turned out for some of the databases it accesses, I needed to increase permissions.

Now, I have another issue about `inserting duplicate field into dbo.SharedFields`, but that's another question for another time!